# Are main and fopen valid variable names?

Tags: c, keyword

The C standard says variable names should not match with standard C keywords and standard function names. Then why does the code below compile with no errors?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int main = 10;
    printf("Magic is %d", main);
    return 0;
}
```

See also http://codepad.org/OXk4lZZE

In an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25891420/123109) below, ouah writes

> `main` is not a reserved identifier and it is allowed to name variables
>   as `main` in C

so considering the program below, does that mean that `fopen` is likewise not reserved?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int fopen = 10;
    printf("Magic is %d", fopen);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The C standard says lotsa things ...

Comment: Interestingly, the whole "main as a global variable" concept was employed in 1984 by one Sjoerd Mullender in the International Obfuscated C Code Contest. See it [here](http://ioccc.org/1984/mullender.c).

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You program is a valid C program.

`main` is not a reserved identifier and it is allowed to name variables as `main` in C.

What you cannot do is name a variable `main` at file scope but this is the same as with other variables that would conflict with a function of the same name:

This is not valid:

```
int main = 0;

int main(void)
{
}
```

For the same reasons this is not valid:

```
int foo = 0;

int foo(void)
{
    return 0;
}
```

**EDIT:** to address the OP question edit, the second program in OP question is also valid as C says

> (C11, 7.1.3p1) "All identifiers with external linkage in any of the following subclauses (including the future library directions) and errno are always reserved for use as identifiers with
>   external linkage."

but the `fopen` variable identifier has block scope and none linkage in the example program.

Comment: Be aware also that because you include `<stdio.h>`, `fopen` might be a function-style macro. Then it wouldn't be portable ("strictly conforming") as certain kinds of variable, specifically a function pointer that you call like `fopen(whatever)`, since that would expand the macro. It will work as a variable name provided the implementation hasn't defined it as a macro, or if you never write the variable name immediately before a `(`, so it's quite a fine point of portability...

Comment: This is distinct from the fact you already give, that standard library function names are reserved for use with external linkage, since that linkage rule applies even if you never include the relevant header. And can't reliably be worked around by any means other than consulting the reserved identifiers and the "future directions".

Comment: @SteveJessop It's an interesting point, thanks for the comment. In OP's example with `fopen` declared as an `int` the fact that `fopen` may be defined as a function-like macro in the header has no incidence. But a different example with a function-pointer type and a call to the pointer would be problematic indeed.

Answer (score 1):

By default the global variables and the functions are `extern`  in nature where as in block scope they are `auto` by default.

To check how the linker resolves the symbols check [here](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-linkers-resolve-multiply-defined-global-symbols/)